# How to return a list in the winning-hands function of poker?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

as I mentioned earlier that I'm working on poker hands in clojure, I'm on its final stages of completion. I'm just having problem in its winning-hand function, which should be like it returns the hand from a list of hands that is the highest, but if there are ties, then it should return the list of all of those hands.
So, here is my winning-hand function:

```
(defn hand-rank
              "Return a value indicating how high the hand ranks."
              [hand]
              (let [ranks (card-ranks hand)]
                (cond
                 (and (straight ranks) (u-flush hand)) (-> [] (conj 8) (conj (apply max ranks)))
                 (kind 4 ranks) (-> [] (conj 7) (conj (kind 4 ranks)) (conj (kind 1 ranks)))
                 (and (kind 3 ranks) (kind 2 ranks)) (-> [] (conj 6) (conj (kind 3 ranks)) (conj (kind 2 ranks)))
                 (u-flush hand) (-> [] (conj 5) (conj ranks))
                 (straight ranks) (conj [4] (apply max ranks))
                 (kind 3 ranks) (-> [3] (conj (kind 3 ranks)) (conj ranks))
                 (two-pair ranks) (-> [2] (conj (two-pair ranks)) (conj ranks))
                 (kind 2 ranks) (-> [1] (conj (kind 2 ranks)) (conj ranks))
                 :else (-> [0] (conj ranks))
            )))

            (defn winning-hand
              "Return the max hand of the given poker hands."
              [hands]
              (let [min-count (count (apply min-key count (for [hand hands]
                                                            (hand-rank hand))))]
                (reduce (fn [x y]
                          (if (<= 0 (compare (subvec (vec (flatten (hand-rank x))) 0 min-count)
                                             (subvec (vec (flatten (hand-rank y))) 0 min-count)))
                            x
                            y)) hands)))

            (defn allmax
              "Return a list of all items equals to the max of the sequence."
              [coll]
              (let [maximum (winning-hand coll)]
                (for [x coll :when (= maximum x)]
                  x)))

            (defn winning-list
              "Return a list of winning hands. poker([hand1, hand2, ...] => [hand, ..."
              [hands]
              (allmax hands))
```

The winning-list function works fine when there is no tie, but in case of tie, it is still returning only one hand and not a list of all the hands that are highest. For e.g.: In this case ["AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C"] '["AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H"] '["AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D"] '["AC", "2S", "3H", "4D", "5H"]), it should return '["AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C"] '["AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H"] '["AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D"]. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `allmax` is only returning the hands that are exactly equal to the hand returned by `winning-hand`. It should instead be comparing the score of each hand to the score of the winning hand.

Comment: `(-> [] (conj x) (conj y))` is super-weird. It's a lot simpler to just write `[x y]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing equality on the hand itself, not it's "value" (IE straight flush 1 through 5).  You want something like this.

```
 (defn allmax
          "Return a list of all items equals to the max of the sequence."
          [coll]
          (let [maximum (winning-hand coll)]
            (for [x coll :when (= (hand-value maximum) (hand-value x)]
              x)))
```

An even better solution would probably have you implement a comparator for the hands and use that here and in other places.

Comment: Hi, using the hand-value is giving me the list of winning hands, if any. But I have one issue now. If I input winning-hand (["2H" "3S" "4C" "5D" "AD"] ["TH" "AS" "QC" "KD" "JD"]), then the output should be (["TH" "AS" "QC" "KD" "JD"]) since A beats 5, but by using values I'm getting the output as (["2H" "3S" "4C" "5D" "AD"] ["TH" "AS" "QC" "KD" "JD"]), since both are straight. Can you help me how to deal with this?

Comment: Hello Erica, you need to improve your hand-value/comparator function to take tiebreakers into account.  For example, the tie-breaker for a pair is the next highest card, whereas the tiebreaker for a straight is the highest value in the straight.  If this is for project euler you can message me offline and I have some sample code you can look at.